# where does ...hbm.xml file go?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am a Hibernate newbie, attempting a small hibernate example with an embedded Derby database.  I am developing in eclipse.  I am not using Spring or Maven, I am not setting up a web application, I have no application server.  I will no doubt use some of those if the project gets bigger, but right now I'm just trying to get this example to work.

The error I am getting is:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException: resource: javabeat/net/hibernate/EmployeeInfo.hbm.xml not found
```

and sometimes just:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException: resource: EmployeeInfo.hbm.xml not found
```

Here is my code; I have marked where the error appears to be coming from - eclipse console shows the exception there and stops running, and it's the logical place:

```
package javabeat.net.hibernate;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class JavaBeatHibernateExample
{
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
  {

    configureDerbyEmbedded();

    Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
    cfg.addClass(javabeat.net.hibernate.EmployeeInfo.class);

    cfg.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
    cfg.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "password");
    cfg.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:derby:myEmbeddedDB;create=true");
    cfg.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "admin");
    cfg.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect");
    cfg.setProperty("cache.provider_class", "org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider");

    // Exception almost certainly generated here.
    cfg.addResource("EmployeeInfo.hbm.xml");

    cfg.setProperty("hibernate.current_session_context_class", "thread");
    cfg.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    transaction.begin();
    EmployeeInfo employeeInfo = new EmployeeInfo();
    employeeInfo.setSno(1);
    employeeInfo.setName("KamalHasan");
    session.save(employeeInfo);
    transaction.commit();
    session.close();
  }

  private static void configureDerbyEmbedded() 
      throws ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException
  {
    Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver").newInstance();
  }
}
```

I have the folders in eclipse set up as follows

```
CarRepair
--src
----javabeat
------net
--------hibernate
----main
------resources
--------javabeat
----------net
------------hibernate
```

I have an EmployeeInfo.hbm.xml, and I have put it in the following places:
  src/javabeat/net/hibernate
  main/resources/javabeat/net/hibernate
  main/resources

And I always get the above exception.  In the first, it just says it cannot find the XML file; in the latter two, it prepends javabeat/net/hibernate in front of the XML filename in the error message.

Is the file supposed to be somewhere else, or is there something else I'm supposed to be doing?

EDIT: Could it be something in the xml file itself, with a misleading error message?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd" >
    <hibernate-mapping>
        <class name="javabeat.net.hibernate.EmployeeInfo" table="Employee_Info">
            <id name="sno" column="sno" type="java.lang.Integer">
            </id>
            <property name="name" column="name" type="java.lang.String"/>
        </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: eclipse copies things from src to bin, so this doesn't actually help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have quite a special directory layout. Assuming `src` is a source folder in Eclipse, it will copy all the non-Java files to the classes or bin directory (or whatever directory name you chose for the compiled classes), and the `EmployeeInfo.hbm.xml` should be directly under `src`, since you're telling Hibernate to load it from the root of the classpath:

```
cfg.addResource("EmployeeInfo.hbm.xml");
```

If you place it in main/resources, the code to load it should be

```
cfg.addResource("main/resources/EmployeeInfo.hbm.xml");
```

Why don't you use your own package hierarchy, and thus use the following directory tree:

```
src
  com
    rcook
      myapp
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't work under src either.  I still get the error with javabeat/net/hibernate/EmployeeInfo.hbm.xml in the exception message.

Comment: That's because you also have `cfg.addClass(javabeat.net.hibernate.EmployeeInfo.class)` in your code. This asks Hibernate to load the file `EmployeeInfo.hbm.xml` in the package `javabeat.net.hibernate`. Choose how you want to load the file, either with `addClass()`, or with `addResource()`, but not both.

Comment: ok, now understand I shouldn't load the class from both places, but that doesn't correct THIS error, which specifically says it cannot FIND the xml file.  I've found a way to make it work, though I have to change the addResource statement.  See my answer.

Comment: My apologies -- it DOES work in src, if I carefully remember to tell eclipse to clean and rebuild.  I can load from src the way it was originally, and from the package location if I alter the addResource statement.

Answer (score 1):

As you said you are not using maven, src/main/resources is like any other folder for Eclipse project. Hence just copy hbm file under src folder and remove the "addClass" method.

Comment: For some reason, putting the XML into the src folder doesn't solve the problem.  I found a way to make it work, though I have to change the addResource method above, and yes, I have to remove addClass as well.  I'm going to write up a sort-of answer.  Thanks.

Comment: my apologies, it DOES work to put it into src -- this time I made extra sure I had cleaned and rebuilt, I must have missed that last time.  Thanks -- I'm marking the earlier answer as accepted, since he was first...